# How to change the size of a unicode circle like ⬤ using css?

Tags: html, css, unicode, web-frontend

Trying to place ⬤ inbetween words in a paragraph tag but I want them to be smaller but can't find a way to change the size of it, everything I've tried it just ignores the height change.

Tried ::before with content, placing inside a span, inline html and trying to add styling in the browser

`<p>Thing1 ⬤ Thing2 ⬤ Thing3</p>`

Pretty much want to reduce the size by half, I tried scale as well as that didn't do anything either. I wanted to avoid using JS for it or just styling a span tag to look the same but not sure if its possible to do it with just CSS?

Comment: It's going to have to be targeted by an HTML element like a `span`/`i`/`b` (with a class) around it.

Comment: Why don't you just use smaller bullets, like • ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the size by using the font-size property. An example is below, hope this helps

```html
<i style="font-weight:700; font-size:16px; font-style: normal;">&#9432</i>
```

Comment: Wow I feel stupid lol thanks so much! Didn't think of using font-size haha

Comment: No worries mate, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform: scale(.5); display: inline-block;` to make it scale down to 50% its original size.

Keep mind this method retains the original real estate of the element, it only changes its rendering size.

Answer (score 0):

Use `font-size` to scale, essentially, and wrap it in some inline element, like `span` or `i` or `b`.

Use `em` units ([MDN intro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units#Length_and_size)) so it's directly relative to surrounding text.

```css
.dot {
  font-size: 0.65em; /* 65%, essentially */
}
```

```html
<p>Something <span class="dot">&#x2B24;</span> smaller, <span class="dot">&#x2B24;</span> please.</p>
```